How to get value based on letter grade with index
I created a key based on letter grade. I am looking to run a lookup that will match that grade and then return the monetary amount back that is in the key.
The formula below is returning a value. However, many times it isn't the correct value. For the cell labeled "developer", it looks like the lookup is returning the "D" grade, despite that not being a grade.
What am I doing wrong?
I'm running this formula:
=LOOKUP(F13,$I$2:$I$9,$J$2:$J$9)



The old LOOKUP function goes by approximated matching. If an exact match isn’t found, it will match to the next closest value.
So in this case C- is matched to C and all the words are matches to the highest value D.
Instead, you really want to use the VLOOKUP function, which is "a much improved version of LOOKUP". Something like:
=VLOOKUP(F13,I2:J9,2,FALSE)


or XLOOKUP if they have Excel 2021 or higher.

Thanks! Not sure why I didn't think to just use the Xlookup. I saw this example and thought it was a new version of the lookup.
